# Using intent to move to the second page

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have made a button in `MainActivity` to go to `SecondActivity`.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="178dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Moj przycisk" />
```

And the method:

```
public void onClick(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.telefon2.SecondActivity"));
}
```

In the manifest file the name of second activity is:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.telefon2.SecondActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
</activity>
```

But when I click the button I get an error:

```
03-12 18:56:08.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1154): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 18:56:08.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1154): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-12 18:56:08.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2683)
03-12 18:56:08.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void onClick(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.telefon2.SecondActivity"));
    }
```

should be

```
public void onClick(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), SecondActivity.class));
    }
```

Since you didn't define an Intent-Action for your SecondActivity (as shown by your manifest).

If you do want to make this Activity exported, by all means, give it an Intent-filter with the action you want:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.telefon2.SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.telefon2.SecondActivity"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Then you can continue using

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.telefon2.SecondActivity"));
```